# Google Fit Recording API, no automated storage of fitness data and SessionAPI recording data within a Session

Tags: java, android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I was reading this thread, but my problem seems more serious. 
[the thread: Google fit Recording Api Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739599/google-fit-recording-api-delay/37956082#37956082)

- How long is the delay usually?
  According to the documentation, if I subscribe the dataSources for the dataTypes I want to record and store in the Google Fitness Store, RecordingAPI will take care of it for me. However, I keep querying the data, and no data is returned.
- Secondly, for now, I would like to record live data within a workout Session. So, I have a method that is called when the user clicked the "Start Workout Session" button, and starts a new session, using SessionAPI, and then stops the session, when the "End Workout Session" is called. Then, the session is inserted without any dataset because I query the data using the start and end times of that session, assuming that RecordingAPI will do automated storage of data during that session. However, no data is returned, when I do the querying.
  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I've actually resolved the issue; however I still have some issues with other features. Would you mind taking a look? I can post the code if you still want to take a look.

Comment: I think it would be best to file another question for your issues with other features.