# Steps is updated with too much delay when read from Google Fit History

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm writing an app using `Google Fit Recording` and `History` API. Do everything same with its docs, and realize that it's worked. However, when I do read `History` every 30 seconds, the steps does not update as quick as I expect.

Suppose, in 30 seconds, I walked (or shake device) 30 steps, if I open `Google Fit` app, the steps is often updated really quick. However, My app needs 1 or even 2, 3 minutes to update these achieved steps.

So, Is there a way to make my app reads `History` steps as quick as `Google Fit` app? or just better than current.

Comment: did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850995/4704510

Comment: @UsamaAmjad sure that I checked. However, I just concern why the Fit service returns steps to my app is slower too much than Fit app? Also, Fit app does not show steps realtime, so I think they do not use Sensor API for showing step realtime (ofcourse, inside it, I don't know).